# Трансляция С++-кода для Java-машины

Tags: java, c++

Так получилось, что я много работал на С/С++ и не работал на Java. А теперь, смотрю, для мобильных платформ Java очень востребована. Я, как разумно-ленивый человек, хочу избежать полного изучения Java. Хотелось бы писать по-прежнему на С++, но чтобы транслировался С++-код не в нативный код, а в код для Java-машины.

Вопрос:

1. Есть-ли сейчас технологии, где С++-код транслируется не в нативный код для конкретной платформы, а в код для Java-машины? С тем, чтобы потом этот код выполнялся как Java-код на Java-машине на любой платформе.

UPD1:

По моим понятиям Java-код сейчас транслируется в некий промежуточный код для абстрактной Java-машины. На разных платформах есть JIT-транслятор, который при запуске этого кода переводит его в нативный код для данной платформы и запускает. Или я не прав?

UPD2:

Вроде бы чего проще. Взять транслятор GCC, оставить синтаксический анализатор а вместо кодогенератора под платформу x86 написать кодогенератор под Java-машину. Неужели еще никто не сделал такой гибрид?

UPD3:

Тогда второй вопрос, связанный с первым:

Вопрос:

2. Как распространяются Java-программы? Распространяются ли Java-программы в исходных кодах, или Java-программы распространяются в кодах для Java-машины?

Comment: мобильные платформы в частности поддерживают приложения на C/C++. 
Ну и Вы сам представляете как это будет работать? как C++ будет транслироваться в Java? там разное по сути все

Comment: @Tsyklop [как C++ будет транслироваться в Java] Хочется немного не того. Не С++ транслироваться в Java, а С++ в код транслироваться в код для Java -машины.

Comment: Как минимум под андроид есть альтернатива: fat binaries - упаковка нескольких бинарников под самые распространенные архитектуры (3-4?) в один .apk. С такой фичей зачем транслировать в байткод?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [С такой фичей зачем транслировать в байткод?] Если такая возможность есть, то это почти решает мою задачу. Но все-таки таскать с собой несколько нативных кодов это не комильфо. Хотя бы потому, что размер бинарника увеличивается в 3-4 раза. А если появитя новая платформа? Надо будет снова строить .apk. Тоже нехорошо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Да, это минус. Но можно собирать и отдельные .apk. Например, гугл плей, ЕМНИП, позволяет загружать разные .apk для разных архитектур, и автоматически подсовывает пользователю нужный. Или он может сам разделить 'толстый' apk на несколько.

Comment: Ну в любом случае вы не сможете один и тот же код без модификаций поднять на любой платформе. Но если вы хотите писать на c++ под андроид, к примеру, то там есть NDK. Понятное дело, все равно придётся делать связующее Java-звено, но вы спокойно сможете использовать свои c++ наработки.

Comment: Насколько я помню в стандартной JVM нет адресной арифметики, поэтому память, с которой  работает C++ (C) программа придется эмулировать очень большим байтовым массивом. Скорее всего тут и кроются проблемы эффективности и поэтому идея не пошла в массы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть-ли сейчас технологии, где С++-код транслируется не в нативный код для конкретной платформы, а в код для Java-машины? С тем, чтобы потом этот код выполнялся как Java-код на Java-машине на любой платформе.

Есть парочка, но не факт что это работает для мобильных платформ и что этим реально удобно пользоваться при разработке:

[nestedvm](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/):

> NestedVM provides binary translation for Java Bytecode. This is done by having GCC compile to a MIPS binary which is then translated to a Java class file. Hence any application written in C, C++, Fortran, or any other language supported by GCC can be run in 100% pure Java with no source changes.

[GCC-Bridge](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/tree/master/tools/gcc-bridge):

> GCC-Bridge is a C, C++ and Fortran to Java bytecode compiler.
>   GCC-Bridge uses GCC as a front end to generate Gimple, and then
>   compile Gimple to a Java class file.

[Набор библиотек и инструментов для LLVM для компиляции C в JVM bytecode](https://github.com/davidar/lljvm):

> The C to JVM bytecode compilation provided by LLJVM involves several
>   steps. Source code is first compiled to LLVM intermediate
>   representation (IR) by a frontend such as llvm-gcc or clang. LLVM IR
>   is then translated to Jasmin assembly code, linked against other Java
>   classes, and then assembled to JVM bytecode.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Судя по тому, что все самый свежий из этих проектов заглох 2 года назад, тема действительно не востребована.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 на мой взгляд проще java освоить, чем работать с этими инструментами.

Comment: [проще java освоить] Тут одно связано с другим. Если бы тема была востребована, то эти инструменты довели бы до коммерческого использования. И народ работал бы на С++ и транслировал бы код для JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте по порядку:

> Есть-ли сейчас технологии, где С++-код транслируется не в нативный код для конкретной платформы, а в код для Java-машины?

Такие технологии есть, но только в виде некоего research'а в глубочайшем бета, а продуктиве нет таких технологий.

> По моим понятиям Java-код сейчас транслируется в некий промежуточный код для абстрактной Java-машины. На разных платформах есть JIT-транслятор, который при запуске этого кода переводит его в нативный код для данной платформы и запускает. Или я не прав?

Как бы верно, но вся проблема в том, что эта работа производится на стороне виртуальной машины, то есть JVM получает байткод и отправляет его JIT, который переводит его на платформенно-зависимые инструкции.

> Вроде бы чего проще. Взять транслятор GCC, оставить синтаксический анализатор а вместо кодогенератора под платформу x86 написать кодогенератор под Java-машину. Неужели еще никто не сделал такой гибрид?

Нет не проще, в С/С++ управление памятью это забота программиста (средства языка), а в Java это функционал, который решается средствами JVM (вне самого языка) - пока вы не устраните это противоречие вы не получите полноценную С/С++ в смысле семантики.

> Как распространяются Java-программы? Распространяются ли Java-программы в исходных кодах, или Java-программы распространяются в кодах для Java-машины?

Java программы распространяются в виде объектных кодов `.class` собранных в архивы `.jar/ear/war/zip`

Для Android обычно упаковываются в архивы `APK`, которые содержат байткод инструкции транслированные в виртуальную машину Android (она не совпадает с байкодами JVM)

**Update**

По VM в Android. Dalvik и ее более новая инкарнация ART - отличаются от Sun JVM тем, что Android машинка имеет регистрориентированную архитектуру в отличие от сановской которая имеет стекориентированную архитектуру, что влечет за собой экономию оперативной памяти актуальной для телефонов/смартфонов.

Dalvik начиная с версии 2.2 имеет JIT, которые компилируется в нативные коды в момент первого запуска, в ART используется ее аналог которые называется AOT (Ahead-Of-Time) который компилирует в нативные коды уже в момент установки.

Comment: [пока вы не устраните это противоречие] Это как раз при трансляции С++ в байт-код устранить не проблема. В простейшем случае надо все указатели при delete передавать сборщику мусора вот и все.

Comment: [она не совпадает с байкодами JVM] Вроде я слышал, что теперь Android выбросил свою самописную Dalvic и пользуется стандартной JVM от SUN-Oracle. Но это не точно да и не суть важно. То есть программы на Java распространяотся в бинарниках для Java-машины. Вот и надо С++ код транслировать в код для Java-машины. Тогда миллионы программистов на С++ смогут работать для Android без переучивания.

Comment: [но только в виде некоего research'а в глубочайшем бета] Почему? Неужели не востребовано на рынке?

Comment: [но вся проблема в том, что эта работа производится на стороне виртуальной машины] Честно говоря, не вижу здесь проблемы.

Comment: Чтобы не создавать отдельный вопрос, заодно хотел спросить специалиста по Jave. Действительно ли байт-код интерпретируется в Java-машине? Или байт-код один раз в начале переводится в нативный код и потом выполняется как нативный код в процессоре?

Comment: 5 комментариев с интервалом в 1 минуту заставляют задуматься о ясности ваших суждений и вообще :)

Comment: Наоборот, 5 комментариев с интервалом в 1 минуту заставляют позавидовать скорости с которой я соображаю.

Comment: Ну раз вы так считаете - дальше уж сами соображайте, но не забывайте народную мудрость: *дурная голова - рукам покою не дает* :)

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: А, ну вот так я и думал. Никто не интерпретирует байт-код. А все транслируют байт-код в нативный код и выполняют нативный код. Хотя действительно, в литературе бродит утверждение, что байт-код интерпретируется. Наверное перевод какой-то неточный.

Comment: Байт-код в общем случае интерпретируется. Горячие места по мере накопления статистики компилируются оптимизирующим JIT-компилятором.

Comment: @Barmaley, не добавите в ответ про [GraalVM/Sulong](https://github.com/graalvm/sulong) как наиболее свежую реализацию цепочки C/C++→LLVM→JVM/GraalVM ?

Answer (score 0):

Как чисто нахватавшийся по верхам теоретик... :)

1. Не слышал. Теоретически, конечно, возможно, но есть масса нюансов - одна только сборка мусора чего стоит - которые будут приводить к достаточно извращенному коду на Java.

UPD1. Не совсем. Байт-код выполняется в режиме интерпретации, по ходу выполнения анализируется, и "горячий" код компилируется в машинный - эдакое сочетание обоих вариантов.

UPD2. Опять же - не слышал. Наверное, можно, но ведь пишут не все, что можно, а что востребовано :) Кстати, там своя четкая спецификация байт-кода, весьма специфичная, так что это совсем не такая простая задача: байт-код - это далеко не ассемблер...

2. Вообще-то для того и разрабатывался байт-код и спецификация JVM, чтоб бинарники сразу везде работали, и можно было именно их распространять, а не тягать исходники и компилировать для каждого утюга отдельно.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

Comment: [Байт-код выполняется в режиме интерпретации] Сразу быстродействие падает в 100 раз. [ "горячий" код компилируется в машинный] Если есть возможность компилировать байт-код в машинный, то почему бы 1 раз в начале не сделать это для всего кода, чтобы потом вообще не терять быстродействие?

Comment: [а не тягать исходники и компилировать для каждого утюга отдельно.] Что байт-код компилировать в нативный код, что исходники компилировать в нативный код разницы никакой. Только что для байт-кода проще написать спецификацию. А ЯВУ постоянно хоть чуть-чуть да меняют синтаксис и теряют обратную совместимость.

Comment: Чтоб я тут не переписывал прямо из книг... Первая - Блох, "Эффективное программирование на Java", вторая - Эванс, "Оптимизация Java". Я опирался на материал этих книг... P.S. На русском языке пока первой есть только старое издание, но обе анонсированы в "Диалектике" как скоро выходящие. Так что пока могу посоветовать только английские издания.

Comment: Я тоже читал разные книги и тоже видел там утверждения что байт-код иногда интерпретируется, а иногда компилируется в нативный код. Не то, чтобы я подвергал сомнению Ваши слова. А просто странно, что если есть возможность сразу конвертировать байт-код в нативный код этой возможностью не пользуются и (якобы) часть кода интерпретируют. Как-то это не логично. Ну да ладно. Это так, просто мое брюзжание в пространство. В ИТ много чего такого, что народ темнит как это сделано внутри. То-ли плагиата боятся, то-ли боятся что над ними смеяться будут, если увидят как это на самом деле сделано.

Comment: Могу только выдрать текст 10 главы из книги Эванса :) Там масса тонкостей, которые надо учитывать. Вобщем, что читал - то рассказал, а как относиться - ваше дело: или возмущаться, что мир не такой, как я его представляю, или научиться жить в том мире, который есть...

Comment: [или научиться жить в том мире, который есть] Не стоит прогибаться под изменчивый мир. Вот думаю, может самому взять GCC или clang какой-нибудь и прицепить к нему кодогенератор для Java-машины. Не быстрее ли это получится, чем выучить Яву.

Comment: Попробуйте, будет очень интересно потом сравнить работу двух типов приложений...

Comment: Clang? Он основан на llvm, у которого нет встроенного сборшика мусора. Java не на быстродействие нацелена а на стабильность работы. Да, они используют кучу хаков для оптимизации как при компиляции в байткод так и при непрерывной работе приложения. Но естественно это будет медленней чем цпп. Чувак, чо ты извращаешься? После цпп ява тебе покажется простой как валенок, а использование языка цпп на jvm не избавит тебя от необходимости изучать библиотеки явы. Короч не натягивай ужа на ежа, пиши уже или на цпп, или на jvm-языках.

Answer (score -1):

Если хочется под мобилки да и на C с крестами, Ваш путь должен лежать к [Qt for mobile](https://www.qt.io/mobile-app-development/) Я правда сам не пробовал, но Qt зарекомендовавший себя тул, и думаю там все в порядке. Из плюсов - Вы не ограничены только Android.